# Django:Applying filter() function is giving NameError

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, manytomanyfield

```
Class Connect(models.Model):
    connection = models.Charfield(max_length=120)
```

Values of 'connection' field of objects of 'Connect' model can be `Chat`,`Video` or `Call`.

Following is my `Visitor` model which has `connecting_medium` as **many to many** field.

```
Class Visitor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    connecting_medium = models.ManyToManyField('Connect')
```

What i know that if `v` is an object of `Visitor` model then the following line of code will give list of connection for this particular visitor `v`.

```
connection_list=list(v.connecting_medium.values_list('connection',flat=True))
```

Now my motive is to get all those `Visitor` objects which have `Chat` in their `connection_list`. I have written the following code but it doesn't seem to work.It is raising an error that:

> name 'connecting_medium' is not defined.

```
def my_view(request):
    context['list_no'] = Visitor.objects.filter('Chat' in list(connecting_medium.values_list('connection',flat=True)))
        #--------------------rest-of-the-code----------------------------#
```

**P.S:** Above code is only sample.I am not allowed to post source code of company's project.But the situation is exactly like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you write queries in Django. You need to use keyword arguments.

In this case, use the double-underscore syntax to traverse the relationship:

```
Visitor.objects.filter(connecting_medium__connection='Chat')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following retrieves all **Visitors** objects with a **Connect** whose connection is **Chat**:

```
Visitor.objects.filter(connecting_medium____connection='Chat')
```

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups... [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).